# Is it possible to populate data with respect to other fields not _id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

All of the time populating `data booking_unique_id` is giving me `null`.

Here is the schema:

```
const chat = require('../models/chat.model')
const booking_details = new Schema({
    booking_unique_id:{type:Object,ref:chat,field:'chat_screen_id'}
    });
```

```
const chat_details = new Schema({
    ...
    receiver_public_name:{type:String}
    chat_screen_id:{type:Object}
    });
Booking.find({booking_status:'e'}).populate('booking_unique_id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not supporting in `ref populate`, there are issues in Mongoose [Issue-3225](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3225), and [Issue-1888](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1888),

For the alternative they have published [populate-virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals),

- chat schema

```
const chat_details = new Schema({
  ...
  receiver_public_name: { type: String }
  chat_screen_id: { type: Object }
});
```

- booking schema

```
const chat = require('../models/chat.model');
const booking_details = new Schema({
  booking_unique_id: { type: Object }
});
```

- booking virtual

```
booking_details.virtual('bookings', {
  ref: chat, // The model to use
  localField: 'booking_unique_id', // Find booking where `localField`
  foreignField: 'chat_screen_id', // is equal to `foreignField`
  // Query options, see /mongoose-query-options
  // options: { sort: { name: -1 }, limit: 5 } 
});
```

- booking model

```
const Booking = mongoose.model('Booking', booking_details);
```

- booking find query with populate

```
Booking.find({ booking_status: 'e' }).populate('bookings').exec(function(error, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: yes after search and test one day i complete this with aggregate. Yes virtual also an option but I found aggregate more flexible to use.Thanks for your answer.